# Article rendering different in community

Tags: apex, community, css, customer-community

My article rendering in  community is not working fine . It is taking the default CSS theme , and showing some ambiguous result.

Is there any possibility to override the css for article rendering in community article in the community builder section using new CSS.

Is the new css will effect the article section only.

Kindly let me know the possibility.

Comment: Do you use custom CSS for your article?

Comment: I am not using although just asking if i use , it will override or not the whole css theme for the articles @Rao

Comment: I am not too sure, but when I was reading through lightning https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/05/loading-external-js-css-libraries-lightning-components.html the document says that you can use a cssnamespacer and prevent your custom css affecting the entire look and feel. I have issues too when working with community, the standard app.css is messing up with bootstrap/ thirdparty css. The only alternate i can think of is namespace the elements and mark them important wherever the app.css is messing up custom css styling.https://bootstrap-namespacer.herokuapp.com/